# reverse function in mylist standard ml

Tags: list, reverse, sml

I want to make a function that reverse a custom list, but it's not working, I've been suggested a function in a previous question, but it used another function, I want to use it without any outside function, I've wrote some code and I would appreciate some tips on how to make it work.

```
datatype 'element mylist = 
  NIL
| CONS of 'element * 'element mylist;

fun reverse (CONS(x, NIL)) = CONS(NIL, x)
  | reverse (CONS(x, xs)) = CONS((reverse xs), CONS(x, NIL));
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
stdIn:89.5-90.60 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [circularity]
  expression:  'Z mylist mylist mylist
  result type:  'Z mylist mylist
  in declaration:
    reverse =
      (fn CONS (<pat>,<pat>) => CONS (<exp>,<exp>)
        | CONS (<pat>,<pat>) => CONS (<exp>,<exp>))
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have switched the order of the head and tail of the list. You defined `CONS of 'element * 'element mylist`, so it should be used as `CONS(head, tail)`. You use it as `CONS(tail, head)` in `reverse`. Because of this, the two clauses indicate contradictory types for `reverse`, and you get the error. Reversing the order of the arguments is not enough to turn `CONS` into an `append` function.

Your reverse function should have a form with clauses that follow the constructors for the datatype. One possibility is like this:

```
fun reverse NIL = NIL
  | reverse CONS(x, xs) = (* implementation for CONS *)
```

Probably a bit easier is to add a second argument that you use to build up the result. It should look like this:

```
fun reverse'(NIL, result) = result
  | reverse'(CONS(x,xs), result) = (* implementation for CONS *)
```

and be called like `reverse'(lst, NIL)`.

I've left out the implementation for the `CONS` clauses, as you've marked the question as homework.